# Laravel 5.5 jQuery ajax method

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5.5

**Hello Everyone**

I am stuck with a peculiar problem. The following code is my Controller Function

```
public function populateIndustry(Request $request) {

    if($request->isMethod('post')) {
        $var = "Post Method";
    } else {
        $in_id = $request->industry_id;
        //$var = $request->industry_id;
        $var = IndustryAction::where('industry_id',$request->industry_id)->toSql();
    }   
    return response()->json($var);
}
```

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(".edit_industry").click(function(e){
  $.ajax({
    url: "populateIndustry",
    type: "get",
    data: { 
      '_token':$('input[name=_token]').val(),
      'industry_id':$(this).data('id'),
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });    
});
```

So as you can see I am trying to check the query and I found that the `industry_id` field is not populated in this query:

```
select * from `industries` where `industry_id` = ?
```

whereas with this line of code I found that the correct id is returned

```
//$var = $request->industry_id;
```

Can anyone  point out my mistake?

Comment: You are miss understanding what is supposed to be returned.  `select * from industries where industry_id = ?`  is correct.  The `?` is expected because it is understood the id is a variable.

Comment: What should be done in this case then? please guide. Because i am expecting a query like { select * from industries where industry_id = 1}

Comment: One moment and I will put it in an answer

Comment: Sure. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
 $var = IndustryAction::where('industry_id',$request->industry_id)->get();
```

And do you have some erros or so? Did you check for typos?

Comment: see I have edited the question and shown you the query which is displayed in the console

Comment: tosql() is great for quickly seeing the SQL. But it doesn't include the query bindings, only a ? for where they are to be inserted.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot for clearing my doubt. Understood

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do something like this if you know the query format:

```
$query = IndustryAction::where('industry_id',$request->industry_id);
$stub_sql = $query->toSql();
$values = $query->getBindings();

$var = str_replace( '?', $values[0], $stub_sql );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Much needed help

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way instead..

Enable query log and then

```
//enable the log first
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::enableQueryLog();

 $var = IndustryAction::where('industry_id',$request->industry_id)->get();

 return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::getQueryLog();
```

You will get back json with the bindings like

```
query:  "select * from `industry_action` where `id` = ?"
bindings: 
    0:  12
time:   0.62
```

Where "12" is your id

Comment: Thanks a lot. was stuck the whole day